# change color of status bar according to content beneath it

Tags: ios, swift3, uistatusbar

We do have so many question here on turning status bar to white color but I wanna know how can I turn it to white or black according to content beneath the status bar same as iOS 9's music app does, is it possible to make this change dynamically with any api or do I have to manually decide the color of status bar?

This is how I'm turning it to white now (which is not what i want):

In `info.plist` assigning `NO` to this  `View controller-based status bar appearance`. then in my `app delegate's` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` :

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decide manually status bar color. You can check for is background of status bar is darker then show light content style.

You can check UIColor is darker or not by below code.

```
extension UIColor
{
    func isLight() -> Bool
    {
        let components = CGColorGetComponents(self.CGColor)
        let brightness = ((components[0] * 299) + (components[1] * 587) + (components[2] * 114)) / 1000

        if brightness < 0.5
        {
            return false
        }
        else
        {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you get help or have any query on the same.

Comment: thanks for responding man . appreciate your effort , i get that  how i'm gonna check the color's darkness but i have no idea how i'm going to get the color of statusBar's background

Comment: Default status bar it self has a clear background color. So you only get a color from object or view which was show behind the status bar ..

Comment: if you have any problem then provide more details about you uiview controller ...